# SPCheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn in Poweshell

Tags: powershell, file, check-in

How we can OverwriteCheckIn in Powershell?
Please correct second parameter?

```
$ListItems[$i].File.CheckIn("Checkin automatically",SPCheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn) // second parameter seems wrong
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reference static types and enums use a `[]` notation:

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPCheckinType]::OverwriteCheckIn
```

Comment: Just for clarification, OverWriteCheckIn will checkin files that are checkedout by other user, right?

Comment: SPFile::CheckIn with SPCheckinType::OverwriteCheckIn as the second argument will check in the file without creating any version - minor (1.1) nor major (2.0). You should test if it suites your requirements or maybe start a new question here in SP.SE